# How kubernetes external ip multi-pod routing works?

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I have bare metal Kubernetes cluster with haproxy ingress controller (daemon set) on external ip. Is it possible to restrict kube-proxy to route to local haproxy ingress pod?

To be more specific, I have 2 pods of haproxy ingress controller and use one external ip for them. As per my understanding, kube-proxy will be routing in round-robin to the pods. I didn't find any way to restrict this particular behaviour.

Comment: What you mean is you don't want pods to bind on port from external IP ?

Comment: To be more specific. I have 2 pods of haproxy ingress controller and use one external ip for them. As I understood kube-proxy will be routing in roundrobin to them. I didn't find any way to restrict that behaviour to local pod.

Comment: I think you mean each node has one instance of haproxy ingress controller as daemonset exposed as NodePort, so each HaProxy has an external IP and a port > 30000. So if your want  roundrobin to access haproxy ingress controllers, you need a load balancer.

Comment: No, I'm using external ip in service. I Have real ports like 80 443.

Answer (score 4):

Set `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` in the NodePort Service.

This will make it so that traffic going to a node X will only go to the pod in node X. If there is no pod in node X the traffic will be dropped (but this should not be an issue since you're using a DaemonSet).

Another benefit is that this preserves the true source IP that haproxy sees. Without `externalTrafficPolicy`, it is possible that haproxy sees the source IP of another node instead of the original one, since nodes can proxy traffic.

More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip)